# echo <br/> into value using php

Tags: php

Need to echo < br/ > into the value for use with dymo printer it uses the value with markup within it to format the label. But it seems like its being treated as a tag and not a string.

```
"<input type=" . "button" . " " . "value=" . $firstname . "<br/>" ." ". $lastname ." ". "onclick=" . "printLabel(this.value)" . " " .
"id=" . "printLab" . ">";
```

So it renders like this:

```
value="jamie<br/>tipper"
```

Comment: you should consider using a hidden textfield.

Comment: You realize that doing `"<input type=" . "button"` is effectively `<input type=button`, which isn't compliant at all. Use escapes.

Comment: @Qix - Attribute quotes are optional in many cases in HTML 4 and 5. XHTML requires (double) quotes, but virtually nobody in practice should be using the XHTML group of `doctypes`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a space between your `<br/>` and your `$lastname` variable, causing the code to spill off into the screen.

A solution to this is to wrap your attributes in quotes.

```
echo "<input type='button' value='$firstname<br/>$lastname' onclick='printLabel(this.value)' id='printLab'>";
```